# why there is a large difference between google analytics and node_counter in drupal

Tags: apache, drupal, nginx, google-analytics

I have drupal 6.25. i was having something very relative between node_counter and google analytics. but recently i started to get a very large difference. for example node_counter shows that i have 1247 views for an article while GA shows 30 page views. i tried to refresh the page and the counter in node_counter has been increased by 1. 
the only new change on my website is that i switched my webserver from apache to nginx.
any idea of what might cause this large difference between Drupal statistics and Google analytics?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Obviously, your node_counter counts every single view regardless of any other parameters. GA probably takes user IP and time since last visit into account to get rid of these (fake) numbers.

Comment: @Paul : definitely, drupal counts views regardless the ip address. but also GA counts Pageviews and "Unique Pageviews"... so at least pageviews of GA should be near to node_counter. but this is not the case!! here is my question.